# Sublime Text doesn't recognize my installed module?

Tags: python, module, autocomplete, sublimetext, auto

Hi I'm a complete beginner at Python and Sublime Text, but I'm trying to follow a video tutorial online and I followed along by downloading Python3 and creating a Python3 Build System in Sublime Text and installing Requests from my Mac Terminal. My problem is when I go to try and import requests, requests is seen as a string type I guess, but definitely not a module type which is what was shown in the video tutorial. When I run Python3 in my Terminal and type import requests, it works! Idk why Sublime Text is showing "abc" and not "module" as the type. [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmM2E.png)

Comment: Can you run the script on terminal? Like `python script_name.py` . Does it give any error?

Comment: It does not give any error. My script name is main.py and inside of that file all I wrote was import requests, and on the next line i did print("it worked"), and my terminal, after i wrote python3 main.py, printed "it worked"

Comment: I don't see the problem then. Sublime shows `requests` just so that you can code quicker. Do you have any problem running the requests module?